# Prepration when replacing lawn with new variety of grass

Tags: lawn, weed-control, sod

I'm in Southern California. I'll be re-sodding a lawn that was/is primarily crab grass with either a fescue or Bermuda grass.

The current lawn has been dying due to lack of water. After I have this grass removed, is there any soil preparation I should do before putting the replacement sod down? I'm specifically concerned about mitigating future growth of the crab grass. If preparation requires time (like waiting for a herbicide to do its job), how long should this take before I can put the new sod in? Or can this just be managed through regular lawn care treatments after the re-sodding?

Correction: I was just informed that the existing grass is kikuyu (pennisetum clandestinum). It is not crab grass.